# Using Typeorm to return ROW_NUMBER() from a Postgres database

Tags: javascript, postgresql, typeorm

Im struggling to work out how to use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function with Typorm and Postgres to return the row number dynamically for an ordered query. Information on this can be found [here](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-row_number/).

One thing to point out is that I have worked out how to do this in Typeorm, using `getRawMany()` (explained below) however it seems wrong to create an entity and then not return the fields of the entity (using `getMany()`).

I have the following entity:

```
@ObjectType()
@Entity()
export class Photo extends BaseEntity {
  @Field(() => ID)
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number

  @Field()
  @Column('text')
  name: string

  @Field()
  @Column('int', { default: 0 })
  like_count: number
}
```

I want to use the `row_number()` function to "rank" the photos based on their position in an ordered query. For example, ordering by `like_count` will return `row_number` `1` for the first, `2` for the second and so on.

The query for this is as follows:

`select *, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY like_count desc) from "photo" p`

Running this query directly on the table returns the `row_number`, as expected:

```
| id| name | like_count | row_number
| --| ---- | -----------| ----------|
| 3 | Zebra| 29         | 1         |
| 1 | Dog  | 23         | 2         |
| 2 | Cat  | 9          | 3         |
```

However, when using the Typeorm `createQueryBuilder`, no `row_number` is returned:

```
await getConnection()
      .createQueryBuilder()
      .select('photo')
      .addSelect('ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY "like_count" DESC)')
      .from(Photo, 'photo')
      .getMany()
```

```
| id| name | like_count |
| --| ---- | -----------|
| 3 | Zebra| 29         |
| 1 | Dog  | 23         |
| 2 | Cat  | 9          |
```

Just to reiterate again: if I use `getRawMany()` here instead of `getMany()`, then `row_number` is returned. Therefore, I believe my `createQueryBuilder` is syntactically correct. It just seems like a "hacky" wrong solution to use `getRawMany` here.

Does anyone know of a solution to return `row_number` in a less hacky way? My thought is that I need to have a field on my `Photo` entity, but I dont think there is any Typeorm field/column/generated decorator for the value of the PostgreSQL ROW_NUMBER Function, nor do I think there is a Typeorm Function I can chain from the `createQueryBuilder` for this?

Comment: Have you found the solution? Im stuck in same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately not - I only managed to get this working using getRawMany as I say in the question. Its a bit of a pain because I then need to create a new type for it and convert values stored in my database, which use an underscore notation (eg, photo_date) to camel case which my frontend expects (eg photoData). But it does work at least.

Answer (score 2):

You can try .getRawMany() instead